# While trying to use SCALA UDF in PySpark, despite providing the --jars : ERROR : pyspark.sql.utils.AnalysisException: u'Can not load class

Tags: scala, apache-spark, pyspark, user-defined-functions

I am trying to use scala UDF in PySpark.

I have created a jar file, which have a scala UDF, the code for which looks like:

```
package example
import org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.UserDefinedFunction
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
object UDF_Scala_code {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    getFun()
  }
  def getStringLength(s: String) = s.length
  def getFun(): UserDefinedFunction = udf(getStringLength _)
}
```

Using Spark 2.4

I am getting an error for below line in pyspark code (use_scala_udf1.py):

```
spark.udf.registerJavaFunction("get_col_len", "example.UDF_Scala_code.getFun", StringType())
```

Command I am running is:

```
spark2-submit --jars /path/ws_spark_scala.jar use_scala_udf1.py
```

ERROR:

```
pyspark.sql.utils.AnalysisException: u'Can not load class example.UDF_Scala_code.getFun, please make sure it is on the classpath;'
```

However if I use below code in Pyspark, I get the expected result.

```
_string_length = sc._jvm.example.UDF_Scala_code.getFun()
return Column(_string_length.apply(_to_seq(sc, [col], _to_java_column)))
```

Thanks.

Comment: The setup is wrong. Please look at this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49632670/5761558

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using Scala classes as UDF with pyspark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49632117/using-scala-classes-as-udf-with-pyspark)

Comment: Yes, it does solved the issue. Thanks