# Registering Scala Functions as Java Functions in Pyspark via UDF1 (struct & case classes)

Tags: java, python, scala, apache-spark, pyspark

I have a Scala case class as

```
final case class TestStruct(
    num_1: Long,
    num_2: Long
        )
```

I have a method that converts string to struct and want to use it in pyspark. I define the following class:

```
package com.path.test

// other imports including Gson, etc.
import org.apache.spark.sql.api.java.UDF1

class TestJob extends UDF1[String, TestStruct] {
  def call(someString: String): TestStruct = {
      // code to get TestStruct from someString
  }
}
```

Then I register it in pyspark using

```
spark.udf.registerJavaFunction("get_struct", "com.path.test")
```

But when I use `df = spark.sql("select get_struct(string_col) from db.tb")`, it returns an empty struct. Even when I use `df.printSchema()` it just shows `struct (nullable = true)` and not the fields of it (`num_1` and `num_2`)

Other people have shown success with integers (links below), but not with struct / case class data types:

[spark-how-to-map-python-with-scala-or-java-user-defined-functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33233737/spark-how-to-map-python-with-scala-or-java-user-defined-functions)

[using-scala-classes-as-udf-with-pyspark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49632117/using-scala-classes-as-udf-with-pyspark)

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Try using `java.lang.Long`, perhaps. Scala's `Long` is not the same as Java's boxed `Long`.

Comment: The real case class has other fields as well including `Map[String, Int]` for some fields and other case classes as other fields. Everything should be Java data types, and not scala?

Comment: I think so, yes (but don't take my word for it, try out a minimal example first).